# Fetching values of the dynamically added checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to retrieve checkboxes value which are dynamically added. Here is what i have done

View:

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.List as List<m_valuation>)
{

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Print</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Txt")</td>
            <td>Codes With</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBox("Check")</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Codes",item.point_valuation)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

}

<input type="submit" value="GenerateCodes" />
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult PrintPointCodes(int DealNo)
    {
        List<m_valuation> model = db.m_valuation.ToList();
        ViewBag.List = model;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PrintPointCodes(List<string> Txt,List<bool> Check)
    {
        List<bool> CheckedItems = new List<bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Check.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckedItems[i] = Check[i].Equals(false);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The returned values comes with true and false . Not sure Where i am going wrong
Please Help me!
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Do you want the true and false values or what is it you want?

Comment: Would you please ask a question or describe your problem? As you write it now it behaves excactly like it should but you have no idea what you are about to do

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You say you're trying to retrieve checkbox values, but then show your `PrintPointCodes` has that collection of true/false you are looking for ...

Comment: @Pavenhimself Yes I want the true and false values of the respective checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.CheckBox` (and`@Html.CheckBoxFor`) methods render 2 controls, `<input type="checkbox" ..>` and `<input type="hidden" value="false">`.  The reason is that unchecked checkboxes to not post back so the second hidden input ensure that `false` is returned is the associated (real) checkbox is unchecked.  Handling checkboxes this way (as an array of boolean values) will not work. If you were to render the html manually then you would only get `true` values and you would not be able to tell which ones were checked on the client.

To correctly bind your properties, render you controls in a `for` loop or use a custom `EditorTemplate` for class `m_valuation`

GET method

```
public ActionResult PrintPointCodes(int DealNo)
{
  List<m_valuation> model = db.m_valuation.ToList();
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model List<m_valuation>
...
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Txt)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Check)
}
```

POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PrintPointCodes(List<m_valuation> model)
{
  //model will be correctly bound
```